# Error in 2D Convolution in Keras

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I know this type of question has been asked many times here, but I could not figure out the answers from those questions. I have a 100x100 image in grayscale. I get the following error while trying to perform 2D Convolution in the very first layer.

```
    import theano
    from keras.layers import Activation, Flatten, Dense
    from keras.layers import Convolution2D,MaxPooling2D
    from keras.models import Sequential

    nb_epoch = 40
    batch_size = 32
    nb_classes = 2
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,3,border_mode = 'valid',subsample = (1,1),init = 'glorot_uniform',input_shape = (1,100,100)))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))

    train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range = 300,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    vertical_flip = True)

    test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

    train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='binary')

    validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=16,
    class_mode='binary')

    model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    samples_per_epoch=nb_train_samples,
    nb_epoch=nb_epoch,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    nb_val_samples=nb_validation_samples)
```

I am getting an error like this: Error when checking model input: expected convolution2d_input_1 to have shape (None, 1, 100, 100) but got array with shape (32, 3, 100, 100). I am not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=16,
    color_mode='grayscale',
    class_mode='binary')

    validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    test_data_dir,
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=16,
    color_mode='grayscale
    class_mode='binary')
```